# Git push no me funciona: "No se pueden enviar referencias al remoto. Intenta ejecutar 'Pull' primero para integrar tus cambios"

Tags: git, vscode, bitbucket

He hecho los últimos cambios que necesitaba para dejar mi programa listo para que esté en el repositorio, pero ahora siempre que intento hacer un git push, ya sea con la extensión de Visual Studio Code o desde la terminal, me salta este error:

[Error al hacer git push](https://ibb.co/WnpZsPQ)

Ya he probado haciendo git pull y git pull --rebase origin master (en mi repositorio solo hay 1 branch, la de master), pero ni esto ni de momento nada he encontrado que solvente esto.

¿Qué debo hacer, por favor?

Muchas gracias.

Edit: en respuesta a eftshift0, dejo lo que ocurre al ejecutar el comando git log --all --graph --oneline

- ad0ee47 (HEAD -> master) Cambios masivos
- 40e13b3 Más cambios masivos
- 8657f17 Cambios masivos
- 6547d1c Cambios generales al main y añadida la opción de cambiar licencias para Usuarios
  | * 127aa18 (origin/rolivait/backups.py-1672397823053) backups.py edited online with Bitbucket
  |/
  | * 7f3cf4c (origin/rolivait/openMaintenanceWindow.py-1672393487375) openMaintenanceWindow.py edited online with Bitbucket
  |/
  | * c829a2b (origin/rolivait/openBackupWindow.py-1672393401191) openBackupWindow.py edited online with Bitbucket

He puesto la parte de esto que parece ser lo más reciente. Esto aparentemente se separa por unos ....skiping... como indico en la siguiente imagen:

[....skiping... que separa por bloques](https://ibb.co/sWDwHqg)

Comment: Pareciera que hay una divergencia entre tu rama local y la del repositorio. Podrías colocar la salida de este comando en la pregunta? `git log --all --graph --oneline`

Comment: @eftshift0 hecho

Comment: Creo que la lista como la pusiste tiene duplicados. Podrías limpiarla?

Comment: @eftshift0 Vale, a ver si con esto sirve. Como indico en la pregunta editada, hay unos ....skiping... que separa por bloques lo que aparece en esa salida. He puesto lo que parece ser lo más reciente (la parte más arriba).